# MPAndroidChart not showing MarkerView

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have the following MarkerView:

```
public class DiagramLineMarker extends MarkerView {
    private TextView textViewValue = null;

    public DiagramLineMarker(Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);

        this.textViewValue = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.line_fragment_marker_textview_value);
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry entry, int dataSetIndex) {
        this.textViewValue.setText("" + entry.getVal());
    }

    @Override
    public float getXOffset() {
        return - (getWidth() / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public float getYOffset() {
        return - getHeight();
    }
}
```

And i set it like it is shown in the `LineChartActivity1` example from MPAndroidChart:

```
this.lineChart.setMarkerView(new DiagramLineMarker(this.getActivity(), R.layout.activity_diagrams_line_fragment_marker));
```

Unfortunately nothing happens when i select a value.

Complete implemenation:

```
public class DiagramLineFragment extends DiagramBaseFragment {
    private LineChart lineChart = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setRetainInstance(true);
        this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        this.sessionLoginPreferences = new SessionLoginPreferences(this.getActivity());
        this.sessionLoginSingleton = SessionLoginSingleton.getInstance(this.getActivity());
        this.sessionProfilePreferences = new SessionProfilePreferences(this.getActivity());
        this.sessionMeasureDataPreferences = new SessionMeasureDataPreferences(this.getActivity());
        this.sessionMeasureDataList = SessionMeasureDataList.getInstance();
        this.sessionMeasureDataListFavourite = SessionMeasureDataListFavourite.getInstance();

        if(this.sessionMeasureDataList.getMeasureDataList() == null) {
            this.sessionMeasureDataList.setMeasureDataList(new MeasureDataList());
        }

        if(this.sessionMeasureDataListFavourite.getMeasureDataList() == null) {
            this.sessionMeasureDataListFavourite.setMeasureDataList(new MeasureDataList());
        }

        Bundle extras = this.getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras != null) {
            if(extras.getString(Globals.KEY_EMAIL_FAVOURITE) != null) {
                this.favourite = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_diagrams_line_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        this.lineChart = (LineChart) view.findViewById(R.id.line_fragment_line_chart);
        this.lineChart.setDrawUnitsInChart(false);
        this.lineChart.setStartAtZero(false);
        this.lineChart.setDrawYValues(false);
        this.lineChart.setDrawXLabels(false);
        this.lineChart.setDrawBorder(false);
        this.lineChart.setDrawLegend(true);
        this.lineChart.setDescription("");
        this.lineChart.setNoDataTextDescription("");
        this.lineChart.setHighlightEnabled(true);
        this.lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        this.lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        this.lineChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        this.lineChart.setPinchZoom(true);
        this.lineChart.setMarkerView(new DiagramLineMarker(this.getActivity(), R.layout.activity_diagrams_line_fragment_marker));
        this.lineChart.setHighlightIndicatorEnabled(true);
        this.lineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        this.fragmentBecameVisible();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.diagram_activity_actions, menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if((this.sessionMeasureDataListFavourite != null || this.sessionMeasureDataList != null) && this.lineChart != null) {
            this.fragmentBecameVisible();
        }
    }

    public void fragmentBecameVisible() {
        this.initData();
    }

    private void initData() {
        List<MeasureDataListEntry> measureDataListEntry = null;

        if(this.favourite) {
            measureDataListEntry = this.sessionMeasureDataListFavourite.getMeasureDataList().getMeasureDataListEntries();
        } else {
            measureDataListEntry = this.sessionMeasureDataList.getMeasureDataList().getMeasureDataListEntries();
        }

        ArrayList<String> xValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Entry> yValuesMonday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ArrayList<Entry> yValuesTuesday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ArrayList<Entry> yValuesWednesday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ArrayList<Entry> yValuesThursday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ArrayList<Entry> yValuesFriday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ArrayList<Entry> yValuesSaturday = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ArrayList<Entry> yValuesSunday = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        for(int i = 0; i < measureDataListEntry.size(); i++) {
            String StringValue = measureDataListEntry.get(i).getTime();
            Long value = Long.parseLong(StringValue) * 1000;
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
            String date = dateFormat.format(new Date(value));

            xValues.add(date);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < measureDataListEntry.size(); i++) {
            String stringValue = measureDataListEntry.get(i).getValue();
            int dayOfWeek = Helper.getDayOfWeek(measureDataListEntry.get(i).getTime());
            float value = Float.parseFloat(stringValue);

            switch(dayOfWeek) {
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                yValuesMonday.add(new Entry(value, i));
                break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                yValuesTuesday.add(new Entry(value, i));
                break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                yValuesWednesday.add(new Entry(value, i));
                break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                yValuesThursday.add(new Entry(value, i));
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                yValuesFriday.add(new Entry(value, i));
                break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                yValuesSaturday.add(new Entry(value, i));
                break;
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                yValuesSunday.add(new Entry(value, i));
                break;
            }
        }

        LineDataSet lineDataSetMonday = new LineDataSet(yValuesMonday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_monday));

        lineDataSetMonday.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
        lineDataSetMonday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramGreenColor));
        lineDataSetMonday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramGreenColor));
        lineDataSetMonday.setLineWidth(1f);
        lineDataSetMonday.setCircleSize(4f);
        lineDataSetMonday.setFillAlpha(65);
        lineDataSetMonday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramGreenColor));

        LineDataSet lineDataSetTuesday = new LineDataSet(yValuesTuesday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_tuesday));

        lineDataSetTuesday.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
        lineDataSetTuesday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramOrangeColor));
        lineDataSetTuesday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramOrangeColor));
        lineDataSetTuesday.setLineWidth(1f);
        lineDataSetTuesday.setCircleSize(4f);
        lineDataSetTuesday.setFillAlpha(65);
        lineDataSetTuesday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramOrangeColor));

        LineDataSet lineDataSetWednesday = new LineDataSet(yValuesWednesday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_wednesday));

        lineDataSetWednesday.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
        lineDataSetWednesday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramPinkColor));
        lineDataSetWednesday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramPinkColor));
        lineDataSetWednesday.setLineWidth(1f);
        lineDataSetWednesday.setCircleSize(4f);
        lineDataSetWednesday.setFillAlpha(65);
        lineDataSetWednesday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramPinkColor));

        LineDataSet lineDataSetThursday = new LineDataSet(yValuesThursday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_thursday));

        lineDataSetThursday.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
        lineDataSetThursday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlackColor));
        lineDataSetThursday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlackColor));
        lineDataSetThursday.setLineWidth(1f);
        lineDataSetThursday.setCircleSize(4f);
        lineDataSetThursday.setFillAlpha(65);
        lineDataSetThursday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlackColor));

        LineDataSet lineDataSetFriday = new LineDataSet(yValuesFriday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_friday));

        lineDataSetFriday.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
        lineDataSetFriday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlueColor));
        lineDataSetFriday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlueColor));
        lineDataSetFriday.setLineWidth(1f);
        lineDataSetFriday.setCircleSize(4f);
        lineDataSetFriday.setFillAlpha(65);
        lineDataSetFriday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramBlueColor));

        LineDataSet lineDataSetSaturday = new LineDataSet(yValuesSaturday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_saturday));

        lineDataSetSaturday.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
        lineDataSetSaturday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramRedColor));
        lineDataSetSaturday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramRedColor));
        lineDataSetSaturday.setLineWidth(1f);
        lineDataSetSaturday.setCircleSize(4f);
        lineDataSetSaturday.setFillAlpha(65);
        lineDataSetSaturday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramRedColor));

        LineDataSet lineDataSetSunday = new LineDataSet(yValuesSunday, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_sunday));

        lineDataSetSunday.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
        lineDataSetSunday.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramYellowColor));
        lineDataSetSunday.setCircleColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramYellowColor));
        lineDataSetSunday.setLineWidth(1f);
        lineDataSetSunday.setCircleSize(4f);
        lineDataSetSunday.setFillAlpha(65);
        lineDataSetSunday.setFillColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.diagramYellowColor));

        ArrayList<LineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<LineDataSet>();

        dataSets.add(lineDataSetMonday);
        dataSets.add(lineDataSetTuesday);
        dataSets.add(lineDataSetWednesday);
        dataSets.add(lineDataSetThursday);
        dataSets.add(lineDataSetFriday);
        dataSets.add(lineDataSetSaturday);
        dataSets.add(lineDataSetSunday);

        LineData data = new LineData(xValues, dataSets);

        if(!this.favourite) {
            float hyper = (float)this.sessionProfilePreferences.getProfile(this.getEmail()).getHyperGlycemia();
            float hypo = (float)this.sessionProfilePreferences.getProfile(this.getEmail()).getHypoGlycemia();

            if(hyper > 0.0) {
                LimitLine limitLineHyper = new LimitLine(hyper);
                limitLineHyper.setLineWidth(4f);
                limitLineHyper.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
                limitLineHyper.setDrawValue(true);
                limitLineHyper.setLabelPosition(LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT);

                data.addLimitLine(limitLineHyper);
            }

            if(hypo > 0.0) {
                LimitLine limitLineHypo = new LimitLine(hypo);
                limitLineHypo.setLineWidth(4f);
                limitLineHypo.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
                limitLineHypo.setDrawValue(true);
                limitLineHypo.setLabelPosition(LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT);

                data.addLimitLine(limitLineHypo);
            }
        }

        this.lineChart.setData(data);
        this.lineChart.animateXY(1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

Layout for the Marker:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line_fragment_marker_textview_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you found the solution? I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.

You must call super on refreshContent function, to update MarkerView. But using the new lib version. See code below:

```
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

    tvContent.setText("" + e.getY());

    // this will perform necessary layouting
    super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the layout of your marker try setting `layout_width="50dp"`. Give it a particular width same goes for the textview layout_width. I was also having a problem in displaying first then by setting the layout_width property, it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thats really weird.
Actually your code should work. Have you made sure that you did everything exactly as in the example in `LineChartActivity1`?

Maybe you could try to provide a different kind of `Context`?
(instead of `this.getActivity()`)

Also you could try moving the code for setting up the `LineChart` into the `onCreateView(...)` method.

Comment: could it be related to the fact that i use the LineChart in a Fragment? I updated my post to provide the full implementation of my Fragment

Comment: Unlikely. The example project also uses the MarkerView in combination with a Fragment: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/fragments/BarChartFrag.java

Comment: What does your layout file for the MarkerView look like?

Comment: i added it to my post. the `refreshContent` of the markerview gets called everytime when i click on a point but nothing is showing up.l

Comment: Try using "wrap_content" instead of "match_parent" for the linearlayout

Comment: Do you have inside your layout activity_diagrams_line_fragment_marker, the line_fragment_marker_textview_value?

Comment: i added log output to the `refreshContent` and it confuses me... when i select a point the output does not show the current point, it shows the previously selected point and it is not called just once it is called multiple times.

Comment: This means the MarkerView is created correctly and its content is refreshed. It is simply not visible. It being called multiple times is quite clear since the chart needs to refresh upon each triggered touch interaction.
Have you tried returning 0 from the getOffset methods?

Comment: Have you cross checked chart background color/grid background color with marker text view ????